# Detect Mobile Device with JavaScript and Razor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, view

I was looking for an easy and lightweight solution to detect Mobile Devices and render the appropiate view.

Unfortunately I am not having much success with my approach.

```
<!-- MOBILE DETECTION SCRIPT-->
<script type="text/javascript">   
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        @ViewBag.IsMobile =true;
}
else{
    @ViewBag.IsMobile = false;
}
</script>

<p>BOOLEAN VALUE IS : @ViewBag.IsMobile
</p>

@if (ViewBag.IsMobile == false)
{
<div id="container">
```

No matter if I use ViewBag or Session or a var, it doesn't work the if-then-else logic.

Please suggest some solution!

Comment: I think you're confusing a server-side language with a client-side language.

Comment: Thanks, I am bit tired I think

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution I found after a few hours looking around is the following (Quick fix, not too dirty):

```
 bool isMobile=false;
    string u = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex b = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex v = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
    if ((b.IsMatch(u) || v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4)))) {
        isMobile = true;
    }
```

later in the same page:

```
@if (isMobile == false)
{
<div id="container">
    <div align="center" style="width: 100%;">
    //some stuff here

...

@if (isMobile == true)
{
//Mobile view here
```

.... no plugins, no download, no redirects....

Comment: A better approach would be to move that code into the controller and return a different view for mobile and desktop clients. Even better would be to move it to a filter or value provider so all your actions know whether the client is mobile or not.

Comment: I think that would be a worse approach, actually. Responsive UI can use css to reconfigure the page layout for desktop, tablet, or phone. IMO, having different pages for mobile devices could get ridiculous to maintain.